# How do I import classes from a prebuilt DLL in either C++ or C#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, zigbee

I am wondering what the procedure is for importing classes from a DLL into a C++ program is? It is a prebuilt DLL made by TI so I don't have access to either the .h or .lib files. I looked around on SO and all of the solutions seem to require that you have developer access to the DLL. Which I am not as I don't work for TI. The loadlibrary function doesn't seem to want to open the DLL. The program fails to open it every time. I am at a loss now and any help is appreciated.

To give context its the TI.ZPI.dll which is used by their program called Ztool to run and manage Zigbee networks. I am trying to access the functions so I can write my own version of Ztool that has more functionality. The literature for the ZPI says it can be implemented in Visual Basic, C#, C++, J# and JScript

Comment: Do not steal proprietary code.

Comment: It is a .NET assembly, not directly usable from an *unmanaged* C++ program.

Comment: How is it stealing if it's open source? And all the tools are free to use?

Comment: Sorry what does unmanaged C++ program mean?

Answer (score -1):

This blog describes how to create a lib from a DLL.

https://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/create-lib-file-from-dll/

I also use depends.exe to see what functions are available in the DLL.  Depends.exe was distributed in older Windows SDKs.

Comment: I have tried that and it returns this


C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>dumpbin /exports C:\ti\simpl
elink\zstack_home_1_02_02a_44539\Tools\Z-Tool\TI.ZPI.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.23506.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file C:\ti\simplelink\zstack_home_1_02_02a_44539\Tools\Z-Tool\TI.ZPI.dll


File Type: DLL

  Summary

        2000 .reloc
       62000 .text





And it basically doesn't extract anything.

Comment: That just means it doesn't have a C functions available.  From you original question, it would appear that this is .NET assembly DLL then.  What happens when you register it, or is it already in the GAC? - from when you installed it.  Is it available as a assembly in Visual Studio?

Comment: Ah ok makes sense. How do I go about registering it? It is not available as an assembly in Visual Studio. It is given when you download a program called Ztool from Texas Instruments. Also depends.exe does not show the functions contained within the DLL despite it showing no missing packages.